# Symfony 3 - How to render and handle the same form in multiple actions in multiple controllers without duplicating too much code

Tags: php, symfony

Using symfony 3, i have multiple controllers and a number of actions all required to render and handle the same form. I'm sure there is a simpler and easier way to do this instead of repeating the form handling code 6 times in every action in every controller.

```
eg

Controller 1{
      action1(){
      //same form handling
      }
      action2(){
      //same form handling
      }
      action3(){
      //same form handling
      }
      action4(){
      //same form handling
      }
}
```

I was wondering if anyone could enlighten me as to how to do this. Thanks

Comment: you need to learn, how's php inheritance works - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Comment: I would suggest that the answer is a simple don't do this.  Ask yourself why you need multiple actions to handle the same form.  Seems like a design problem.  This might help as a start: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html

Comment: thank you very much for the help, i ended up using separate routes to render the forms which worked a treat and reduced a lot of code

Answer (score 1):

You could just add some helper methods to your Controller

```
private function getForm()
{
    // Create form
    return $this->createForm(YourType::class);
}

private function handleForm(Form $form, Request $request)
{
    // Handle the form
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    // Do some stuff
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. In this case you could define a service containing these methods.

Comment: Alternatively you could define an abstract `BaseController` and let your controllers extend this class.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can create a service that can handle the request ...

so you will create your form in your controllers, actions, handle the request from your service, and create the view in the controllers, actions again to render it.

Seams feasible to me...
Hope this will help.

[Edit]
If you don't want to create a service only for this form, 
you can :

- mkdir a folder Handler in your bundle
- create a file xxxHandler.php
- inside it create a class xxxHandler like

  ```
  class xxxHandler {

  public function __construct(Form $form, Request $request, EntityManager $em, $session) {
      $this->form = $form;
      $this->request = $request;
      $this->em = $em;
      $this->session = $session;
  }

  public function process() {
      if ($this->request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
          $this->form->bindRequest($this->request);
          if ($this->form->isValid()) {
             $this->onSuccess($this->form->getData());
                      return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
  }

  public function onSuccess(YourEntity $entity) {
      $this->em->persist($entity);
      $this->em->flush();
  }
  }
  ```

and in your controllers

- instanciate a xxxHandler and give all parameters required. (don't forget use statements)
- and call method proccess() in a 'if'

something like

```
$form = $this->createForm(new yourType, $yourEntity);
    $formHandler = new ProspectHandler($form, $this->get('request'), $em, $session);

    if ($formHandler->process()) {
        //do wathever you want
    }
```

PS: this is old symfony2 methods, modify it a little bit to make it work in symfony3